# Python -- List traversal

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm a bit confused as to why this is not working. I'm writing a simple nested for-loop statement to replace vowels in a String but I'm not getting the expected output.

Using Python 3.5

```
#Excersise to remove vowels in a String

vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

user_in = input("Please enter a string: ")
user_in = user_in.lower()

for c in user_in:
    for vowel in vowels:
        if vowel == c:
            new_string = user_in.replace(c, "")

print (new_string)
```

Input: "This is a string"

Output: "Ths s a strng

Wondering why the 'a' is still there?

Thanks!

Comment: The program will only ever replace one vowel (a, e, i, o or u). It will replace all occurrences of the last vowel in the string. Hopefully that should point you in the right direction of why it doesn't work.

Comment: It is a common error to modify a string/list that you are iterating over (print the list on each pass if you want).  If not a vowel, append to a second list/string.   Also you can use "if c in vowels" instead of comparing each one to c.

Comment: The 'a' is there because you only save the last replacement in the for loop. So, ... What do you expect the output to be? Do you want to remove all of the vowels or do you want to print the string multiple times, each with a single vowel removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to do this is:

```
accum = ""

for c in user_in:
    if c not in vowels:  # note the reversed logic
        accum += c
```

Or with a list comprehension and `str.join`

```
''.join([c for c in user_in if c not in vowels])
```

The ultimate problem is that every time you remove a vowel, you assign it to a *different* string, which is then discarded on the next iteration. The simple fix of doing `user_in = user_in.replace(c, '')` doesn't work because then you're changing the length of the string, which wreaks havoc when you're iterating over it. You could do

```
for c in user_in[:]:
    if c in vowels:
        user_in = user_in.replace(c, '')
```

Because the slice `[:]` is shorthand for creating a new copy of `user_in` that isn't affected by the replacements, while still letting you operate on a persistent version of `user_in`

Comment: That simple fix **does** work. Try it, and add `print(c)` to see that the iteration isn't affected. It doesn't change the string, it just makes the variable `user_in` reference another string.

Comment: @StefanPochmann hrm you're right. Strings might be special-cased in this way? Modifying the length of the container you're iterating over is scary, and it's best practice not to do that. Apparently I'm hazy on the exceptions where it's okay!

Comment: No, it's not special. That statement explicitly creates a new independent string and leaves the original one alone (the one that's used for iteration). Would work even with lists. Though with a list, you might instead actually *change* the original one, and that's dangerous. But you can't do that with strings, as they're immutable.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, due to how you are checking for vowels in the string, only the last vowels is replaced. Give this a try instead:

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

user_in = input("Please enter a string: ")
user_in = user_in.lower()
new_string = “”

for c in user_in:
    if(c not in vowels):
        new_string += str(c)

print (new_string)
```

This code checks each character in the user input (`user_in`) and adds each character to the output string (`new_string`) if it is not in the list of vowels.

Comment: prefer `c not in ...` to `not (c in ...)`

Comment: @AdamSmith, fair enough. I'll correct that in a second. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The join() method seemed to do the trick. Not sure if it's the most algorithmically efficient but it's passing all tests.

Solution:

```
#Excersise to remove vowels in a String

vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

user_in = input("Please enter a string: ")
user_in = user_in.lower()
new_string = []

for c in user_in:
    if c not in vowels:
        new_string.append(c)

new_string = ''.join(new_string)

print (new_string)
```

Thanks guys!!!!!

Comment: Seems like I overlooked the scope aspect of new_string. I'll try to post a more elegant solution when I can. Thanks for all the help lads/ladies.

Comment: Just updated. Instead of creating a final_string list -- simply just overwrote new_string. Wondering if this is safe practice for python? Is creating a new list more standard?

Comment: yep this is standard. As you get more comfortable in Python you'll start building this in list comprehensions rather than writing `for` loops. `''.join([c for c in user_in if c not in vowels])` is very idiomatic. Much better than the sort of map/filter/reduce stuff you'd see in other languages (`functools.reduce(operator.add, filter(lambda c: c not in vowels, user_in), "")`)

Comment: Cool. Guess I'll do some more reading on list capabilities. I'm a native Java kid, so the transition is a bit perplexing. Thanks though man!

Answer (score 0):

More efficient answer:

```
#Excersise to remove vowels in a String

vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

user_in = input("Please enter a string: ")
user_in = user_in.lower()

user_out = ""

for char in user_in:
    if char not in vowels:
        user_out += char

print (user_out)
```

Comment: I greatly doubt that's faster than using `str.join` on a list.

Comment: I benchmarked it. They're about the same runtime. Base arithmetic seems to be a tiny tiny tiiiiiiny bit faster. Not notably faster mind you. Milliseconds depending on your hardware. I just posted it because it's a tad more readable for future readers to comprehend. Thanks for the help though! :)

Comment: I've personally found using arithmetic operations as opposed to function calls runs faster. No stack memory allocation allows for greater run-time efficiency. At least that's what I was taught in Java. Where memory is a huge factor. Loving Python so far!